# How not to update Gemfile on Jenkins's job with Github update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, jenkins

I'm testing Rails application with Jenkins connecting Github.
When Github receives a push, Jenkins automatically pulls the change.

I want not to update Gemfile, so I set [Gemfile] to Excluded Regions.

my Github root has...

```
Gemfile
config/
app/
lib/
log/
....
```

Source Code Management for Jenkins
selected Git
Repository URL: git@github.com:.....
Excluded Regions: Gemfile

Very appreciated if you give me an advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is that you still see the Gemfile in the Workspace it might be because it is there from a previous checkout.

Wipe out your current workspace to make sure you are really looking at fresh data. Click on 'Workspace' and afterwards on 'Wipe Out Current Workspace'.

EDIT:

After reading your comment I understand your real issue is that you want to have multiple configurations of gems to test against.

There are 2 ways to do this without requiring local modifications to the Gemfile.

Use a number of different Gemfiles (Gemfile1, Gemfile2, ...) all checked in to version control and call bundle install using the [--gemfile](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/bundle_install.html) swith

> `bundle install --gemfile Gemfile1`

This will install the correct gems for the specific Gemfile.

Another solution, especially if you have only a small number of different configurations is to use the [groups feature](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/groups.html) and store all configurations in one Gemfile.

> `bundle install --without group1 group2`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but not works. I want keep Gemfile edited locally(/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/my_project/workspace/), but not to update by polling Github.

Comment: There is probably another (better) solution possible in that case - why do you need the locally edited Gemfile? Isn't there a solution that removes the need for the local edits?

Comment: It's because I want to test my application with various Gemfile(different gems required), so I create some Jenkins projects for each Gemfiles. Is there good solution for testing with this situation?

Comment: Please close your question then, either by adding your own answer and accepting that one, or by accepting my answer (if it indeed solved your problem). This way others will know it doesn't need attention anymore.